# How does total internal reflection cause sparkling of diamonds?

Tags: optics

How does total internal reflection cause sparkling of diamonds? What is the problem with ordinary glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The *index of refraction* for diamond is much larger than for ordinary glass which means the critical angle in air is much smaller.  More rays inside the diamond will experience total internal reflection than would in glass.
2. The *dispersion* value for diamond is much higher than for glass.  In both glass and diamond red and blue light will refract at slightly different angles for the same angle of incidence but in diamond this difference is much greater.